# Unexpected render result, height map too bumpy?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, pbr

I've just started playing with pbr pipelines and I think I have all of these nodes setup correctly, but I'm getting a result that differs from what I'm expected, so maybe I don't?

Here is what I'm expecting:[image]

Here is what I'm getting:
[image]

[image]

And these are the nodes I'm using:
[image]

Does anything stick out as being horribly wrong?

Comment: Greatly appreciated! That took care of it. Updated my question to try to be more specific :)

Comment: Nice ! I've posted the comment as an answer since it seems it helped you. Cheers :)

Comment: @Gorgious upvoted and accepted as this answers my original question. However after further examination I believe I might have something else going on. I created a new question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220562/properly-setting-up-a-height-map-using-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Distance in the bump node is by default in meters. Since it is approximated without actually displacing the geometry, at that scale even very small details in the bump map get blown out of proportion.

Try decreasing that value, it should smooth out the bumpiness.
You can also play with the normal map node strength although I don't think you should have to.