# Properly setting up a height map using nodes

Tags: rendering, materials, height-map

I am attempting to recreate the output I get from materialize in blender using nodes, but seem to be having an issue. This is the result I get from materialize (node the depth in the joints between the blocks):
[image]

And this is the result I'm getting in blender:
[image]

The following is my node setup:
[image]

Is there a way to recreate this effect using a height map within blender (version 2.9)?

Comment: The "magic" of regular bump maps disappears when looking at the texture at grazing angles. Unfortunately in this case I think you'll have to use a heavily subdivided mesh and real displacement to get the same effect. There is parallax occlusion mapping in the works but I don't think it will be available any time soon https://devtalk.blender.org/t/parallax-occlusion-mapping/15774 . My 2 cents

Comment: If you have a normal map and a displacement map, there is no need to combine them. If you just want the bumpy look without loads of geometry, just use the normal map. If you want a hyper-detailed, displaced mesh; just use the displacement map.

Comment: @Gorgious I do believe that's what I'm after. If there's currently no support, that answers my question :)